# HTTP Request headers and caching

Tags: google-chrome, http, caching, microsoft-edge

How should an HTTP Agent make decisions about using cached response when a request has the same path but different headers?

Take for example this HTTP request/response:

```
GET /resource HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
X-Filter: foo=bar

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 13

{"foo":"bar"}
```

Should the agent consider the response valid for a second request with a different `X-Filter` header? For example:

```
GET /resource HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
X-Filter: foo=baz
```

then within an hour from the first request, should the agent request a fresh response since the request header differs, or should use the cached response from the first request, ignoring the header?

I'm asking this because I noticed that Google Chrome makes a new request, Microsoft Edge instead use the cached response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the cached version unless changed header appears in the list provided by [the (optional) `Vary` response header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.4).

> For example, a response that contains
>
> ```
>  Vary: accept-encoding, accept-language
> ```
>
> indicates that the origin server might have used the request's
> Accept-Encoding and Accept-Language fields (or lack thereof) as
> determining factors while choosing the content for this response.